# Keep widget below the statusbar

Tags: android, flutter

is there a way to make sure that a widget keeps underneath the quick menu on android. 
At the moment I do it in a kind of dirty way with a padding parameter, I hope there is a better solution.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.0),
      color: Color(0xff757575),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildHeader(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
              child: TextField(
//                cursorColor: Colors.red,
                maxLines: null,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                autofocus: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Add title",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20.0,
            ),
            TimeAndDateCard(),
            EventEntryCard(
              label: 'Add Location',
              icon: Icon(Icons.place),
              onLongPress: () {
                showSearch(delegate: LocationSearch(), context: context);
              },
            ),
            EventEntryCard(
              icon: Icon(Icons.people),
              label: 'Invite people ',
            ),
            EventEntryCard(
              icon: Icon(Icons.attachment),
              label: 'Add attachment',
            ),
            EventEntryCard(
              icon: Icon(Icons.work),
              label: 'Status',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[layout without padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRVkS.png)

[Wished layout. Container is underneath the statusbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XowJF.png)

Comment: Add a picture of what you want to achieve..!

Comment: I have added some pictures, I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Container` with `SafeArea` and it will do the magic for you..

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(),
   );
}
```

Hope it answers your question..